# PSTricks + pdfLaTeX resulting in fonts not embedding into eventual PDF

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pstricks, embedding

I want my eventual PDF to have all fonts embedded.  Using special `psdots` in pstricks is causing this to fail.  Here is a MWE of something which results in non-embedded fonts:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,epsfig,pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,3)
\psdots[dotstyle=asterisk](0,0)
\psdots[dotstyle=o](0,0)
\psdots[dotstyle=triangle*](0,0)
\psdots[dotstyle=diamond*](0,0)
\psdots[dotstyle=pentagon*](0,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is output from `pdffonts`:

```
[mishchea@linty mwe]$ pdffonts mwe.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SDXKYB+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            Standard         no  no  no      13  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      14  0
```

Comment: Everything is fine with the document! Times-Roman is a default PostScript font and available on all PS-printer or used by one of the GhostScript fonts. The Type 3 font is an internal softfont ehich is created by PSTricks itself on the fly.

Comment: Nevertheless, the entity to which I'm submitting this document insists that all fonts are embedded, so I need to embed this one...

Comment: sure that is no problem. I also prefer embedded fonts and in my local `config.ps` the PostScript fonts are always embedded by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to embed standard PostScript fonts then use

```
\usepackage[dvips={-h tir_____.pfb}]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

that is the setting for Times-Roman. The font file (in this case `tir_____.pfb`) is free available in the net. If you want to embed *all* standard PostScript fonts then use an own `config.ps` file which enables the embedding of these fonts by default, eg:

```
[...]
 % Partially download Type 1 fonts by default.  Only reason not to do
% this is if you encounter bugs.  (Please report them to
% @email{tex-k@@mail.tug.org} if you do.)
j

% load extra header files, in this case fonts used by pstricks header
% and perhaps in other places, bit of a waste but better save than sorry
h hvb_____.pfb
h hv______.pfb
h tir_____.pfb
h tii_____.pfb
h tib_____.pfb
h pzdr.pfb
[...]
```

running `kpsewhich config.ps` in a terminal tells you where your current file `config.ps` is located, eg:

```
voss@shania:~> kpsewhich config.ps
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/config/config.ps
```

And here is the output of your example running with the above -h option:

```
voss@shania:~> pdffonts Test/Namenlos-4.pdf
name                    type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
----------------------- ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
SDXKYB+CMR10            Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
GNSOXG+Times-Roman      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      13  0
[none]                  Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      14  0
```

Comment: How many times do we need to press `_` for the font filename in `\usepackage[dvips={-h tir_____.pfb}]{auto-pst-pdf} `? Because it is not so obvious for a glance sight.

Comment: from history: file names were 8.3 characters. 8 for the name and 3 for the extension.

Comment: Thanks!  I only have one question: does enabling this cause the whole font character set to be loaded into the PDF, or just those characters I actually use?  In other words, if I set my config.ps as described here, will it cause EVERY PDF I generate to have EVERY PostScript font embedded unnecessarily?

Comment: As seen in my output of `pdffonts` it is a subset

Answer (score 4):

I think it is better to use `standalone` class and compile the source with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` compilation sequence to get a tight, single PDF output as follows,

[image]

```
% this file name is goo.tex
\documentclass[10pt,pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-1,-1)(5,5)
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.1](-1,-1)(5,5)
\psdots[dotstyle=asterisk](0,0)
\psdots[dotstyle=o](1,1)
\psdots[dotstyle=triangle*](2,2)
\psdots[dotstyle=diamond*](3,3)
\psdots[dotstyle=pentagon*](4,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Invoking `pdffonts goo.pdf` produces an output as follows,

[image]

### Tips and tricks:

- First, create a single LaTeX input file with `standalone` class for every PSTricks `pspicture` you have in your main LaTeX input file.
- Second, compile each of those `standalone`-based LaTeX input files with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence to produce a PDF output.
- Third, from within your main LaTeX input file, import those PDF output with `\includegraphics` and compile the main LaTeX input file with `pdflatex`.
- Done!

### Does the main LaTeX input file embed the fonts?

```
% this file name is main.tex
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{goo}
\end{document}
```

compile it with `pdflatex main` to produce a PDF file named `main.pdf`. Then check the fonts as follow,

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with the standalone class, but this problem is actually buried in the middle of what typesets to a 160 page document which is a finished product except that this single font will not embed correctly.  It is thus undesirable to change the document class...

Comment: Anyway I just tried the `latex`-`dvips`-`ps2pdf` route, also `latex`-`dvipdf`, on my actual document, and both gave a PDF with the same unembedded font.

Comment: I may end up having to do this, but I have around 90 or so figures... in the future I will try to avoid using my method, which apparently causes problems, but if there is a more workable solution for my actual situation I would prefer it.

Comment: @kissmyarmpit, I don't follow you. Your output of `pdffonts` shows there are embedded Type 3 fonts. What is the main difference between the two outputs ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood the problem... I thought the goal was to get rid of the Type 3 fonts.