# Embed fonts in XeLaTeX PDF output?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdf, embedding

How do I embed fonts in XeLaTeX's PDF output?

I am printing directly onto my printer, which requires PDF, EPS or PS input with embedded fonts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used XeLaTeX for a document which when I open it in Adobe Reader shows that a subset of the font is already embedded. So I think it should be already happening for your document. Just check it in the File->Properties->Fonts settings.

[image: Fonts subset embedded already.]

Comment: Actually I tried printing it just after [reading this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74299) and found that it printed just fine! - Thank you XeLaTeX! :D

Comment: As mentionned [in this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-to-embed-fonts-at-compile-time-with-pdflatex) (for PDFLaTeX), there might still be a problem if you insert images in pdf without embedded fonts.

Comment: I would like to have the font embed fully.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why they don't make this easier to do.

Here is a solution to embedding fonts after you compiled the PDF file:

1. open your pdf file,
2. select file -> print
3. set your printer to be Adobe printer (assuming you already installed it)
4. click on properties
5. click the tab "Adobe PDF Settings"
6. uncheck "Rely on system fonts only; do not use document fonts"
7. click on the Edit... after Default Settings
8. click on Fonts, add those missing fonts to "Always Embed" (It is recommended to save the properties as a new setting.)
9. print the pdf file with the new settings, and your new pdf file should be good to go.

Tip:  when (or if) it asks you to save the PDF settings file, save it in the suggested Adobe settings folder

Source:  [Click Here](http://xiaohui-blog.blogspot.com/2012/04/fixing-font-not-embedded-issue-to-pass.html)

Comment: You don't have to do any of this; XeLaTeX embeds (subsetted) fonts by default (as the accepted answer says).