# PDF output showing blank spaces instead of math

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, output

I have a big problem now. I need to print my thesis tomorrow, but I learned that for mysterious reasons my supervisor most of the time sees blank spaces instead of math symbols in the pdf I send her (and her printer's output looks the same). The symbols she cannot see are latin letters and numbers --- greek letters and other symbols look right.

I cannot test this more thoroughly and I do not know what computer she uses, but I am afraid that a problem like this could happen at the print shop. What scares me the most is that I don't have any idea of what's happening so if there will be a problem I won't know how to solve it.

I attach my preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{a4paper}         
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{%
        /pgf/number format/use comma,%
}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\newcommand{\rttensor}[1]{\overline{\overline{#1}}}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.eps,.jpg}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy,hhmmss]{datetime}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
$p$
\end{document}
```

I am using xelatex for the output and I make extensive use of Unicode for accents, symbols,... so I cannot switch to a dvi->ps->pdf workflow

I am asking you if you know of what maybe causing this problem and what would be some safe method to print out everything, even if not at the best quality, since it is more important to have content.

EDIT: Now it is a MWE. My supervisor wouldn't see the p in math style that is in the document

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What happens if you change the line with hyperref onto `\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}`?

Comment: What @Tobi meant was a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html). Right now, there is no output, so deciding wheter to see anything or not is hard.

Comment: Without a pdf which demonstrates the problem it is difficult to say what's going on. You could try to change the math fonts: `\usepackage{lmodern}` (before fontspec), or even `\usepackage{unicode-math}`. And: why didn't you test how your document prints already weeks ago? What will you do tomorrow if the colors don't look good or some graphic is not acceptable?

Comment: it sounds like the math fonts aren't embedded in the pdf file.  there are quite a few questions here that deal with that problem. it's hard to find one that matches exactly. but this one might help: [Embed fonts in XeLaTeX PDF output?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131667/579)

Comment: Thank you all. However, for @UlrikeFischer ,sharing a pdf is a bit complicated as StackExchange won't host them. I put the PDF generated by me for the MWE in [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tk3o8b4lrc96pd8/mwe.pdf)

Comment: Thank you also to Przemysław. I will try those modifications and show them to my supervisor tomorrow

Comment: That's not really a MWE unless everything there is required to produce the problem. If everything is needed, there's an easy solution because you could surely use the default fonts rather than Hoefler etc. if you had to. Moreover, those are fonts which many users won't have. So they cannot compile your code to reproduce the problem. Take out whatever isn't essential. That's what the 'Minimal' means :).

Comment: The MWE works well on my system, so as the PDF file you provided. BTW, I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

Comment: You all have been helpful however I myself think that this question is hardly answerable (see [the discussion on Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/non-reproducible-problem/3979)) so I am voting to close as "too broad"