# How to embed all fonts with pdfLaTeX in combination with pstricks and auto-pst-pdf

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pstricks, embedding, auto-pst-pdf

The publisher of my thesis asked me to provide a pdf file that meets two conditions:
(1) The pdf file must NOT be created with Ghostscript.
(2) All fonts must be embedded in the final pdf file.

To meet requirement (1), I switched from „latex -> dvips -> gswin32c (Ghostscript)“, i.e., from LaTeX -> PS -> PDF, to `pdfLaTeX`. Since my latex file contains the pspicture environment (`pstricks`), I used the command `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`. Below, you can find a minimum working example (MWE) and the resulting pdf output obtained from pdfLaTeX.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} 
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

\savedata{\Data}[{      
% 1st column: x-values, 2nd column: y-values        
0.05        30.0
0.10        30.0
0.15        30.0
0.20        30.9
0.25        31.5
0.30        33.0
0.35        34.6
0.40        35.5
0.45        37.3
0.50        39.5
0.55        41.7
0.60        43.5
0.65        45.3
0.70        47.0
0.75        49.6
0.80        51.2
0.85        54.4
}]      

\centering
\psset{xunit=14cm, yunit=0.08cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.07,-8.75)(1.05,105) 
\listplot[plotNo=1, plotNoMax=1, showpoints=true, dotstyle=Btriangle, plotstyle=line, dotsize=4pt, linestyle=dashed, linewidth=0.6pt]{\Data}
\rput[l](0.05,60){Dots:}
\psdot(0.1,55) \psdot[dotstyle=Bsquare,dotsize=4pt](0.07,55)  
\end{pspicture} 

\caption{Example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Minimum Working Example]

In regard to requirement (2), I realized that all fonts are embedded in the output file generated by pdfLaTeX except for a few fonts. The non-embedded fonts originate from the `\psdot` command used in some pstricks pictures (see the screenshot showing the pdf document properties with respect to fonts for my MWE). In my example, each of the three dot symobls on its own  (square, dot, triangle) causes the problem.

[image: Screenshot from Adobe Acrobat Professional: Document Properties]

The problem caused by the `\psdot` command has already been treated in this forum (see [question 74277 from September 27, 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74277/pstricks-pdflatex-resulting-in-fonts-not-embedding-into-eventual-pdf)). I tried to apply the answer that was given there, but unfortunately I could not figure it out so far. To be more precise, I downloaded the header file tir_____.pfb from the web and saved it to „C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1\tir_____.pfb". In my latex file, I replaced `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` by `\usepackage[dvips={-h tir_____.pfb}]{auto-pst-pdf}`. But nothing changed with respect to the font issue. A section of the build output that is displayed in TeXnicCenter is given below.

[image: Section of the Build Output in TeXnicCenter]

Can anyone give helpful advice? Do I have to save the header file in another folder? Do I have to save another header file? Do I have to manipulate any map file? (I use MikTeX 2.9, running on Windows 7, 32 bit). If someone could guide me through this, I would be happy.

Kind regards
Matthias Walter

Due to your helpful comments and answers, I realized that the type 3 font is actually embedded. The information provided by two pdf tools (PDF-XChange Viewer and pdffonts) confirms this:

[image: Information provided by PDF-XChange Viewer for the MWE pdf file]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what `tir____.pfb` has to do with `\psdots`. It is the file name of `Adobe Times Roman`.

Comment: The header command doesn't change this T3-font (which is already embedded). It would help if your pstricks pictures would refer to the standard font Times (which they sometimes do).

Comment: Related: [Miktex degrades MnSymbol fonts to type 3 fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342252/13423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Type3 font is a so-called soft font which is a vector font, too. It is defined by PSTricks on-the-fly and embedded by default. You have to use the `dvips` option only for symbols from Times Roman, Zapf Dingbats, or Helvetica.

You have nothing to change! However, most printshops do not know that a Type3 font can also be a vector font.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your help. Indeed, the type 3 font is embedded: The tools PDF-XChange Viewer and pdffonts confirmed this (see the two screenshots that I added at the end of my original question above). I was just confused by the information displayed in the document properties window of Adobe Acrobat Professional.