# Miktex degrades MnSymbol fonts to type 3 fonts

Tags: fonts, miktex, embedding, mnsymbol

I'm having some trouble getting Miktex to correctly include some fonts in my document. The document compiles correctly over linux (texlive 2015) but when I run it over windows (miktex 2.9) it turns the MnSymbol fonts into type 3 fonts. This caused the library to reject the file for my PhD thesis (since it shows up as not having embedded fonts), so I would like to fix this, ideally without having to recompile over linux.

A minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rcirclearrowright}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{248}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lcirclearrowright}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{252}
%

\begin{document}

$\rcirclearrowright$, $\lcirclearrowright$

\end{document}
```

The funky loading of MnSymbol was written as described in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36006/), and it is required because the thesis is pretty bulky and, if I try to include the MnSymbol package directly, I get a "too many alphabets" error.

If I compile this over miktex, I get a `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX2.9/fonts/type1/public/ amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb` font, which is pretty standard, but I also get a type 3 font, `C:\Users\ episanty\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\mnsymbol\dpi600\MnSymbolA10.pk`. This is marked by Adobe Reader as a non-embedded font:

> [image]

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181194/13423) suggests that simply installing the package in the Miktex Package Manager should fix the problem. However, the only action that Miktex offers me with respect to the MnSymbol package is uninstalling it, which I don't think will help.

How can I persuade miktex to embed this properly as a type 1 font?

Comment: MnSymbol does some odd things.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font/269691?s=1|0.3562#269691 for  example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens MiKTeX forgets to launch `updmap` after it installed   font files. Thus the type 1 fonts databases (`psfonts.map` and friends) are not updated. Normally, all you have to do is to run `updmap --verbose` as administrator.

Comment: Well, I'll be. That's possibly the weirdest problem/solution pair I've come across TeX-side. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Miktex doesn't forget it. But if you installed fonts as user you then have user maps.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: It happens MiKTeX doesn't run `updmap`.  I could observe it several times. Everything I've installed is as Administrator.