# Why is MnSymbol not loading Type 1 fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, minionpro, mnsymbol

I am trying to typeset a document with only Type 1 fonts in the resulting PDF. I'm using the **MinionPro** package, which calls **MnSymbol** for math fonts. Even though the Type 1 **MnSymbol** fonts are installed in `~/texmf/fonts`, pdfLaTeX insists on using pk files and producing Type 3 fonts in the PDF output. (I can see this by looking at the log file and the PDF in Evince.)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass {minimal}

\usepackage {MnSymbol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
First, some text. 
Now some math:
$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2.$
\end{document}
```

The same problem is produced by replacing **MnSymbol** with **MinionPro**, and it's worth noting that the log file shows Type 1 Minion Pro fonts files when I do that. So **MnSymbol** seems to be the problem. More evidence for this: if I use no math symbols in the document, all fonts in the PDF are Type 1.

I have found [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342252/miktex-degrades-mnsymbol-fonts-to-type-3-fonts), but the solution proposed there (i.e., run `updmap`) does not seem to work for me. (Perhaps that problem was specific to MikTeX; I'm running a slimmed-down version of TeX Live on a Linux machine.)

A related troubling fact is that MnSymbol.map is nowhere to be seen in the output of `updmap-sys --listmaps`, though MinionPro.map is. So I'm not even sure how pdfLaTeX is finding MnSymbol in the first place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with an up to date TL2018. `pdffonts` tells me, that only type 1 fonts were embedded in your MWE. Maybe you should use your the (TL or MiKTeX) package manager to (re)install MnSymbol...

Comment: Perhaps you could post the (relvant) part of your log file and the output of `pdffonts`.

Comment: What happens if you add `\pdfmapfile{=MnSymbol.map}` to your document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That seemed to fix it! I'm very pleased to have an all-Type-1 pdf, but I'd love to know why that works, and what about my setup has caused this annoying problem.

Comment: (I suspect, as @DG' says, that the MWE I posted should not produce Type 3 fonts, if everything is set up correctly.)

Comment: Well this means that something is wrong with your font map files. What happens if you run `updmap-sys  --enable Map=MnSymbol.map`?

Comment: It ran without complaint, and now pdfLaTeX seems to produce a Type-1-free file without your previous fix. Great!

(I was certain I'd ran that updmap command when I first installed the MnSymbol fonts, but I guess I was wrong.)

Comment: I still don't quite understand why the solution worked. Is `updmap` required to provoke TeX to look for Type 1 font files?

Comment: Yes, map files must be enabled with updmap-sys. Normally today this is done by the package managers when they install a package, but sometimes there can be an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map-file of the font has not been enabled correctly for an unknown reason.

Run on a command line

```
 updmap-sys --enable Map=MnSymbol.map
```

(this is for a texlive system, in miktex it works a bit differently).