# phd thesis, .eps .pdf graphics, missing embedded fonts, me turning nuts!

Tags: fonts

i joined this forum because of a specific question, that i have already spent a few hours on investigating. i am very sure that you can help me, so that i can narrow down my problem.

i have turned in my phd thesis as a pdf to my universities's online publishing platform a few days ago. its a biochemical work lots of graphics, either .eps or .pdf. they came back to me saying that not all of the fonts were embedded into the pdf. i am not a lo9ng time tex'er through and through, but i thought that i know what i am doing, at least until now. i am confident to say that at least i am it affine.

my preamble looks like this:

```
\documentclass
[
%--Sprache
ngerman,
%--Seitenlayout
DIV=11,
BCOR=10mm,
a4paper,
headinclude=true,
footinclude=false,
twoside=true,
%--Schrift/Absätze
parskip=half,
fontsize=11pt,
headings=normal,
numbers=noenddot,
%--Entwurfsschalter
draft=false
]
                                    {scrreprt}

\usepackage                         {selnolig}
\usepackage[crop=off]               {auto-pst-pdf-lua}

\ifpdf
\usepackage                         {fontspec}
\usepackage                         {libertinus-otf}
\else
\usepackage[T1]                     {fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]                   {inputenc}
\usepackage                         {erewhon}
\fi

%--Sprache
\usepackage[ngerman]                {babel}
\usepackage                         {lipsum}


%--Layout
\usepackage                         {tocloft}           % TOC/LOF/LOT
\usepackage[headsepline=0.5pt]      {scrlayer-scrpage}  % Layout
\usepackage                         {soul}

\setul{1pt}{.4pt}% 1pt below contents

\usepackage
    [
    final,
%   activate={true,nocompatibility},
%   tracking=true,
%   kerning=true,
%   spacing=true,
%   factor=1100,
%   stretch=10,
%   shrink=10
    ]                               {microtype}         % Textoptimierung
    
    \usepackage
    [
    pdfauthor={Felix Maximilian Schilcher},
    pdftitle={Barcoding von genomischer DNA und Anwendung im Bereich des DNA-Mappings},
    colorlinks,
    pdfpagelabels,
    pdfstartview = FitH,
    bookmarksopen = true,
    bookmarksnumbered = true,
    linkcolor = black,
    plainpages = false,
    hypertexnames = false,
    citecolor = black
    ]                               {hyperref}
\usepackage[font={small}]           {caption}           % Unter-/Überschriften
\usepackage                         {siunitx}           % SI-Einheiten
\usepackage[version=4]              {mhchem}            % Chemie: Formeln
\usepackage                         {chemnum}           % Chemie: Nummerierungen
\usepackage                         {longtable}         % multi-page Tabellen
\usepackage                         {graphicx}          % Grafiken
\usepackage                         {float}
\usepackage                         {array}
\usepackage                         {calc}
\usepackage                         {lscape}
\usepackage                         {setspace}

%---------------------------------
%-----------Einstellungen---------
%---------------------------------

\captionsetup
{
    format=plain,
    labelfont={sf,bf,small},
    textfont={sf,small}
}

\sisetup
{
    locale = DE, 
    detect-all,
    group-separator = \,,
    range-phrase = --,
    separate-uncertainty,
    multi-part-units = single
}

\newcommand{\itJ}{{\addfontfeature{Alternate=0}\textit{J}}}
%\renewcommand*\pm{\raisebox{.2ex}{$\scriptstyle\pm$}}

\setchemnum{replace-style = \fontsize{8}{9.5}\sffamily}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%-- Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\chead{\headmark}
\automark{chapter}

%-- Überschriften
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{-1cm}}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace*{0.5cm}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0.0cm,tocbeforeskip=0.02cm,beforeskip=0.3cm,afterskip=0.25cm]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0.1cm,tocbeforeskip=0.01cm,beforeskip=0.2cm,afterskip=0.15cm]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=0.2cm,tocbeforeskip=0.00cm,beforeskip=0.1cm,afterskip=0.05cm]{subsubsection}

\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt} % remove indentation from figures in lof
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt} % remove indentation from tables in lot

%-- Tabellenüberschriften/Bildunterschiften
\setlength{\captionmargin}      {1.0em} %links/rechts margin
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}   {2ex} %abstand reset
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}   {1ex} %abstand reset
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textsc{Et.\,Al.~}}

%-- Hurenkinder und Schusterjungen verhindern
\clubpenalty10000
\widowpenalty10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000
```

when i go thorugh the pdf settings - the font tab doesn't show all fonts as embedded subsets whatsoever. i followed this link "https://www.karlrupp.net/2016/01/embed-all-fonts-in-pdfs-latex-pdflatex/" - but modifying the ps2pdf command line in the texlive settings didnt do anything.

similar to a post "https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202709/how-to-embed-all-fonts-with-pdflatex-in-combination-with-pstricks-and-auto-pst-p" i have not 1 but 20 T3 fonts that are not embedded and other than that:

helvetica
helvetica-bold
helvetica-oblique

my pdf contains serveral eps and pdf file from powerpoint, mathlab, origin, chemdraw and so on. i am sure the fonts come from there. problem is, that last time i edited those files was more than 2 years ago and i dont even have the software (origin, chemdraw, ...) liceses anymore.

i am so frustrated, this is the very last challenge regarding my phd, can u please give me a hint at least what to search for next.

damn it, thank you :)

felix

Comment: that ifpdf block looks very strange, you seem to be using luatex given you use ``{auto-pst-pdf-lua}`  but then `\ifpdf` will be true as it is making pdf so you will take the 8-bit pdftex branch with T1 encoding and inputenc?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. Can you, please, reduce your code in a minimal example to compile it to help you? For my humble opinion it is necessary to have a full complete example.

Comment: perhaps you intended `\ifpdftex` at that point?

Comment: fix that ifpdf (which is forcing 8bit fonts) and if you still have issues try to edit the example so you are not asking people to run your test file with shell-escape (which really is a security risk) but is a complete document that is producing a type 3 font in the resulting pdf.

Comment: for the eps files, I would not try to convert them on the fly during the luatex run as that is hard to debug. Just input pdf files and convert them individually with epstopdf on the commandline, then if any specific figures have issues with unusual font references you can try to fix them (or ask about the specific image that is causing problems)

Comment: alright, i changed all eps files to pdf. now i am only stuck with t3 fonts

Comment: use pdffonts utility on each of the converted eps (now pdf) files, see which are using type 3 fonts.  try commenting those out of your document and see if the resulting document pdf then only uses embedded opentype fonts

Comment: alright, did so, figured out which subset of my pdf's (formerly known as eps) files are the problem. as i feared it's the ones i originally exported from origin a couple of years ago. i dont have access to the original origin files anymore nor the software itself. only to the raw data of course. though i have already turned in 10 copies of the printed dissertation and now have to find a way to turn in a pdf thats resembling those copies...

Comment: you can probably embed the fonts with a pdf editor.

Comment: ahall i just imagemagick the pdf to png? or do you have a better idea? btw, i am very greatful of you help. just amazing how you helped me to idetify my problem

Comment: What happens if you put `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` into your preamble?

Comment: IanThompson
doesn't change anything, still T3 fonts
UlrikeFischer
what kind of pdf editor? what exactly should i do?
@DavidCarlisle
you have helped me so much! do you have a final recommendation how to go on?

THX

Comment: Are you using pdflatex or lualatex?

Comment: as @UlrikeFischer says you may be able to substitue the fonts using a pdf editing tool, or by hand editing the eps and then re-converting, but making a high resolution png might be easier and for printing just as good really

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- Is there no way to tell the engine to embed the fonts?

Comment: @IanThompson if an eps  made by some third party tool is using a type3 font and you don't have that font on your filesyetm other than the type3 font embedded in the image then it isn't clear what you can do even in principle, even without worrying about the difficulties technically in changing the internal font structure in a pdf.