# Compiling/viewer problem, so ' is missing in pdf

Tags: viewers, sharelatex

I'm sorry for that bad titel. Thank you that you are here to read my hole problem.

I'm using sharelatex and the Latex compiler (no pdflatex). If I'm inserting a picture it will look in the build-in pdf viewer like that:
[image: First picture]

In the native pdf viewer (or Adobe Reader) the picture looks like that:
[image: second picture]

The ' s are missing. Can anyone help me or know that problem?

I have done a little example from my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[varioref=false]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{bpchem}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 

\begin{document}

some text

\begin{figure}
    \center
    \psfrag*{mark1}[c][c]{\compound{RUBROA}}
    \psfrag*{mark2}[c][c]{\compound{RUBROM}}
    \psfrag*{mark3}[c][c]{\compound{RUBROr}}
    \psfrag*{mark4}[c][c]{\compound{RUBROs}}
    \includegraphics{rubross.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You can find the picture and my complete main.tex [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/us796rkoy5n3e7v/AADb_JtvufFiREy9M2Iswn6Aa?dl=0).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are using the `psfrag` package, which works only with postscript (eps) files; it works by replacing strings in that eps file according to your `\psfrag` definitions. If you compile your document on your machine not with pdflatex but the old-fashioned way with latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf, it should work.

Comment: Yes, it is done like you said it. Do you get a different output?

Comment: Well, I don't have your eps file, so I can't test it. Edit: Sorry, I overlooked the link you had posted. Will test.

Comment: You can find it here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/us796rkoy5n3e7v/AADb_JtvufFiREy9M2Iswn6Aa?dl=0

Comment: Does it work if you use `\usepackage{tgheros}` instead of `\usepackage{helvet}`?

Comment: Your eps uses helvetica but seems not to embed it. This means that the pdf reader has to find a replacement. You could try to add helvetica as header file by using `dvips -h  hv______.pfb main` (you need to find `hv______.pfb` on the net, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74307/2388).

Comment: Hey Ulrike,
`\usepackage{tgheros}` works. thank you! Is tgehros a another font which is similiar to helvet/arial and is supported by the eps?

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but rather a workaround that avoids the use of psfrag. I hand-edited your eps file to remove the legend and then converted to pdf, and I then recreated (part of) the legend in tikz. I can complete the legend and send you the files if you want.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{helvet, mhchem, tikz}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tikzstyle{every node}=[anchor=base, 
                        font=\sffamily\normalsize, 
                        text depth=0,
                        anchor=base west]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]

\path 
(0,0) node {\includegraphics{nolegend}}
(1.5,0.8) node {rubrolide A (\textbf{1a}): R\,=\,Z\,=\,H; L\,=\,Q\,=\,X\,=\,K\,=\,Br}
;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you, that looks good. But I have a lot of pictures like that so I should can do by myself.

Comment: OK, glad it's useful.